# Removing the first frame from an MP3 file

Tags: vb.net, mp3, naudio

I'm trying to remove the first frame/26ms of an MP3 file in Visual Basic. I've found the NAudio library and I've been trying to get it to work but the documentation is non-existent and it seems to be causing me a great deal of annoyance.

```
    Private Sub TrimMp3(inputPath As String, outputPath As String, begin As System.Nullable(Of TimeSpan), [end] As System.Nullable(Of TimeSpan))
    If begin.HasValue AndAlso [end].HasValue AndAlso begin > [end] Then
        Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("end", "end should be greater than begin")
    End If

    Using reader = New Mp3FileReader(inputPath)
        Using writer = File.Create(outputPath)
            Dim frame As Mp3Frame
            While (InlineAssignHelper(frame, reader.ReadNextFrame())) IsNot Nothing
                If reader.CurrentTime >= begin OrElse Not begin.HasValue Then
                    If reader.CurrentTime <= [end] OrElse Not [end].HasValue Then
                        writer.Write(frame.RawData, 0, frame.RawData.Length)
                    Else
                        Exit While
                    End If
                End If
            End While
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

This is the snippet I found, that I converted from C# to VB.net, the problem is I don't know what the length of the incoming file is - so I can't set an end-time.

I've also considered using ffmpeg, but because of the files (one song, split into 12 files), the headers are all over the place, so every time I run

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00.026 -i A.mp3 -acodec  copy A.mp3 -y
```

I get

```
Audio packet of size 44 (starting with C829D411...) is invalid, writing it anyway.
```

Any ideas on how I could achieve this?

Comment: FYI:  [Non-existent documentation](https://naudio.codeplex.com/documentation)

Comment: The question is unclear.  Are you trying to retain the first frame or remove it?  Or are you trying to figure out the total time?